# Find the image of $f(S)$ and draw what's happening

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

$$w=f(z)=z^2$$
$$S=\{z\mid Re(z)=a\}$$

I don't get what this is asking and what that second part means. What is the concept here? If I let $z=x+iy$, then I can square it. The real term is then $x^2-y^2$. The second part of the problem says that the real part of $z$ is $a$. I can totally replace the $x^2-y^2$ with $a$ but that doesn't seem like it means anything. Plus the question seems to be asking what would be happening on a graph, so I don't see how that relates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the $x^2-y^2$ by $a$, that would be saying that the real part of $z^2$ is $a$.  But this is not what the question says, it says the real part of $z$ is $a$.

If $z\in S$ then $z=a+it$, $t\in \Bbb R$, and so
$$z^2=(a^2-t^2)+2ati\ .$$
If we write $z^2=u+iv$ then
$$u=a^2-t^2\ ,\quad v=2at\ ,$$
and you should recognise this as a parametric representation of a parabola.  (Alternative: eliminate $t$ to get $4a^2u=4a^4-v^2$.)

Comment: The $t$ was arbitrarily chosen correct? The standard form uses $a+bi$

Comment: It's just a letter.....

Comment: I used $t$ because people often use that for parametric equations of curves.  You could leave it as $y$, or any letter you like.

Comment: I don't get how I'm supposed to recognize this as a parabola. Could you help me out with that bit?

Comment: OK, never mind the parametric form.  Just look at the last equation of my answer.

Comment: Ahhh I see it now. Thanks for the assist!